# OMNet++ debugging on macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: omnet++

I am using macOS 10.15.2 Catalina and I followed the Installation Guide for macOS. 
I completely followed the Installation Guide and still I am unable to debug.

Anyone encountered the same? or know how to fix it?

Many thanks.
Yasir

$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$-$

#### Adding more details below for @Rudi

When I try to install to install OMNet++ 6 pre 5 and do `make`, I am getting following error and it seems that OMNet++ 6 pre 5 is also not tested for macOS Catalina 10.15.

```
===== Compiling qtenv ==== 
messageanimator.cc
In file included from messageanimator.cc:17:
In file included from ./messageanimator.h:26:
In file included from /Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/QGraphicsRectItem:1:
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:80:1: error: expected expression
public:
^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:7: note: forward declaration of 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
      ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:484:31: error: 'QGraphicsItem' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemFlags)
                              ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:24: note: 'QGraphicsItem' declared here
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:485:1: error: expected expression
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QGraphicsItem, "org.qt-project.Qt.QGraphicsItem")
^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qobject.h:529:65: note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE'
    template <> inline const char *qobject_interface_iid<IFace *>() \
                                                                ^
In file included from messageanimator.cc:17:
In file included from ./messageanimator.h:26:
In file included from /Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/QGraphicsRectItem:1:
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:485:1: error: expected unqualified-id
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qobject.h:529:67: note: expanded from macro 'Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE'
    template <> inline const char *qobject_interface_iid<IFace *>() \
                                                                  ^
In file included from messageanimator.cc:17:
In file included from ./messageanimator.h:26:
In file included from /Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/QGraphicsRectItem:1:
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:595:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem : public QGraphicsItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:7: note: forward declaration of 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
      ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:595:51: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem : public QGraphicsItem
                                                  ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:595:53: error: expected unqualified-id
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem : public QGraphicsItem
                                                    ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:620:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsPathItem : public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:7: note: forward declaration of 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
      ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:620:42: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsPathItem : public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
                                         ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:620:44: error: expected unqualified-id
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsPathItem : public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
                                           ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:653:24: error: variable has incomplete type 'class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsRectItem : public QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem
                       ^
/Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h:78:7: note: forward declaration of 'Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT'
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QGraphicsItem
      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:83: /Users/yasir/omnetpp-6.0pre5/out/clang-release/src/qtenv/messageanimator.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:121: qtenv] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:35: allmodes] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also OMNeT++ 6 pre 5? It contains an lldbmi wrapper executable that would use system provided lldb instead of gdb which may fix a lot of potential problems (and may cause other ones). But it would worth a try.

Even if you get gdb signed properly on macOS it will not support dynamic loading so it would be more or less useless (unless you build everything statically).

Comment: Thanks @Rudi for your answer. I also tried it but getting errors related to Qtenv. I have edited my original question and mentioned the error.

Comment: I will try to find a mac with the appropriate OS version. Indeed the build was not tested with 10.15 as my macMini is too old :(

Comment: Thank you very much. That would be a great help to me. Many thanks.