# MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 - OMNeT++ 5.6.2 stucks at "Configuring GDB"

Tags: gdb, omnet++, macos-catalina

I have a problem in debugging OMNeT++ in my Macbook Pro.

I installed OMNeT++ 5.6.2 on my MBP having macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and tried to run tictoc tutorial. It runs fine, however there is a problem with debugging.

I know that masOS no longer supports gdb and we have to install gdb through Homebrew or Macports and then configure it. I already have set up gdb.
In order to test gdb, I installed eclipse CDT, set up and configure GDB, then started debugging.

It was debugging fine in eclipse. However, when I debug in OMNeT++, it stucks at "Configuring GDB".
[image: OMNeT++ GDB problem]

I also tried with OMNeT++ 5.5.1 but having the same problem.

I also asked it before at stack overflow, but couldn't find appropriate solution.
[MyPreviousQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394876/omnet-debugging-on-macos-10-15-catalina)

**Does anyone know how to fix OMNeT++ debugging issue on macOS?**

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the other SO question: I would also advise to try to use OMNeT++ 6.0 preview 8 on macOS. I have successfully built it on macOS 10.15 and as suggested in the other SO thread, it does use lldb instead of gdb.

An alternate workaround could be to use VS Code with an appropriate extension. I have just published a blog entry related to debugging OMNeT++ models:
https://omnetpp.org/blog/2020/07/05/omnetpp-debugging-tips.html

Comment: I am using Veins with OMNeT++ and Veins is unfortunately not compatible with OMNeT++ 6 preview 8. So, I need to use OMNeT++ 5.5.1 or 5.6.2. 
Thanks for sharing the alternative of using VS code. I will check your provided link and will try it as well.